# Pass a value from DB to a URL as the parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am passing 2 parameters in this below URL. MID and Prac. MID is the user's id which will get passed when the user logs in to the site. Now to get 'Prac' i need to pass this MID to a table in my DB and get the value. Please advice me as to how i should go about this.

```
    a href="@Url.Content("https://something/someserver?%2fWEBSITE%2fProj_FinancialPerf&
    MID="+ Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Replace("***\\", ""))+"&Prac=SOMETHING")"  id="LinkButton7" name="LinkButton7"  new { target = "_blank" }) value="@Resource.Get("ManagerReportsPageInputScreen13_LinkButton7")">
@Resource.Get("ManagerReportsPageInputScreen13_LinkButton7")</a>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could set your Prac to a variable in your model (do this in the controller) then just use that variable like this @Model.Prac

```
Public ActionResult Index(){
    var pageModel = new PageModel;
    pageModel.Prac = "WHATEVERPRACIS"
    return View(model);
}

@Html.ActionLink("button text", "Index" , new { Prac = Model.Prac, Mid = Model.Mid, etc = etc})
```